# How does the compiler interpret this expression, in terms of Precedence and Associativity?

Tags: c++

It's an exercise from *C++ Primer 5th*:

> ```
> Exercise 4.33: Explain what the following expression does(Page158):
> someValue ? ++x, ++y : --x, --y
> ```

The codes:

```
bool someVlaue = 1;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
someVlaue ? ++x, ++y : --x,--y;
std::cout << x << std::endl << y << std::endl;
```

I tried `Gcc4.81` and `Clang3.5`, both gave me:

```
1
0
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Why not `1` and `1`? Can anyone explain how it was interpreted?

Comment: Use a precedence table (e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) to apply parentheses to the expression, and then reassess.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I tried that table, but still can not understand what's going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because of the very low precedence of the comma operator, the expression

```
someValue ? ++x, ++y : --x,--y;
```

is equivalent to:

```
(someValue ? ++x, ++y : --x),--y;
```

So the `++x, ++y` expression is executed (setting `x` and `y` to 1), followed by the expression `--y` at the end, restoring `y` to 0.

Note - the comma operator introduces a sequence point, so there is no undefined behavior from modifying `y` more than once.

Answer (score 4):

The expression

```
someValue ? ++x, ++y : --x, --y
```

is evaluated as

```
(someValue ? ((++x), (++y)) : (--x)), (--y)
```

As you can see, the `y` is modified twice, once incremented and once decremented, thus the result is `1 0` and not `1 1`.